# Matlab: 'Block' matrix multiplication without resorting to repmat

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix **A** (of dimensions *mxn*) and vector **b** (of dimensions *nx1*).

I would like to construct a vector which is `_repmat_((A*b),[C 1])`, where *C = n/m* . I am using a lot of data and therefore *n~100000* and C~10.

As you can see this is really block matrix multiplication without having to explicitly create the *full* **A** block matrix (dimensions *nxn*) as this easily exceeds available memory.

**A** is sparse and has already been converted using the function `_sparse()_`.

1. Is there a better way of doing this? (Considering speed and memory
   footprint trade-off, I'd rather have a smaller memory footprint)
2. Usually if I was doing elementwise calculations, I would use *bsxfun* instead of using *repmat* to minimise memory footprint. As far as I know there is no equivalent bsxfun for matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is time for you to REALLY learn to use sparse matrices instead of wondering how to do this otherwise.

SPARSE block diagonal matrices do NOT take up a lot of memory if you create them correctly. I'll use my [blktridiag](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10603-block-tri-diagonal-matrices) function, which actually creates block tridiagonal matrices. Here I've used it to create random block diagonal matrices. I've set the off-diagonal elements to zero, so it really is block diagonal.

```
A = rand(3,3,100000);
tic,M = blktridiag(A,zeros(3,3,99999),zeros(3,3,99999));toc
Elapsed time is 0.478068 seconds.
```

And, while it is not small, the memory required is not that much more than twice the meemory required to store the diagonal eleemnts themselves.

```
whos A M
  Name           Size                     Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A              3x3x100000             7200000  double              
  M         300000x300000              16800008  double    sparse
```

Here about 17 megabytes, compared to 7 megabytes.

Note that [blktridiag](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10603-block-tri-diagonal-matrices) explicitly creates a sparse matrix directly.